# Issues during installing geth client in windows docker container

Tags: go-ethereum, windows, docker

I have been trying to get a windows instance of a container with geth client installed within it. Following the link below, I have been successfully able to use chocolatey to get go, git, etc.
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Windows
Particularly in the last step of the installation:

```
C:\Users\xxx\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum> go install -v ./...
```

I have been seeing the following issues:

```
open Documents and Settings: Access is denied
open Program Data/: Access is denied
go\src\golang.org\x\net\html\charset\charset.go:20:2: cannot find package "..."
....(GOPATH)
....(GOROOT)
can't load package: package ./tools/go/test found packages...
```

As an alternative I tried attaching to the container and running the command manually and although I dont see the permission denied errors, the errors around finding and loading necessary packages still exist. Any suggestions would be immensely helpful

Comment: Could be a silly suggestion, but have you tried running the your installation commands in administrator mode CMD?

Comment: Yea! Although the initial issue around denied access resolved, the remaining issues still continued to remain

Comment: As the assumption, maybe the problem, that path contains white spaces in the name? Did you try without whitespaces?

Comment: Possibly! Windows Go space instructions in the link below are what I followed - not sure if this has a whitespace issue